# PHP pthread doesnt seems to be multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Please assist if possible. I intended to pull an X amount of rows from a DB, separating them into arrays of 20 arrays and pass them to a thread for processing simultaneously.

To ensure the process was working simultaneously i created a quick thread that echo's out the thread number then counts to 20. I expected to see results like "1 at 1" then "2 at 1". Instead i see the first thread counts to 20 before the second thread begins to execute. ie "1 at 1" ... "1 at 20" then only "2 at 1".

```
<?php
class helloworld extends Thread {
    public function __construct($arg){
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }
    public function run(){
        if($this->arg){
            for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
                echo $this->arg ." AT ";
                echo $i." ";
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Then to call it i use

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$num_threads;$i++){
    $thread[$i] = new helloworld($i);
    if($thread[$i]->start())
        $thread[$i]->join();
}
```

Is what i am seeing correct? Or am i doing something stupid here?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux or? If windows, do you have the correct DLL in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pthread's join() function waits for the thread specified to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then pthread's join() function returns immediately.  The thread specified  must be joinable.

So, you are waiting for each started thread to terminate before moving on in your loop.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

So removing the join should allow simultaneous threads to be run? I see in testing it without the join i get the same result. Do you perhaps know where i can find a working example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologises, i had removed the $i ($thread[$i]) in testing and that seemed to have also caused an issue. Removing the join resolved my problem.

All seems to be working as it should. Really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Here's a good example of a Thread Pool using pthreads in PHP: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/Pooling.php