# PHP pthread not running in multithreading approch

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

**My PHP Pthread code :**

```
<?php

$query="test";
$sits=array('demo1','demo3','demo2','demo3','demo4','demo5','demo6','demo7','demo8');

    class StackableArray extends Stackable { public function run() { } };

    class Storage extends Stackable { public function run() { } };


    $Storage = new Storage();

    class SiteProcess extends Thread
    {   
        private $Storage;
        private $site;

        public function __construct(Storage $Storage, $site,$query)
        {
            $this->Storage = $Storage;
            $this->site = $site;
            $this->query = $query;

        }

        public function run()
        {
            require_once("Sites/{$this->site}.php");        
            $siteObj = new $this->site;     
            $this->Storage[] = $siteObj->getPriceData( $this->query,$cache);                              
        }
    }

    foreach($sites as $site)
    {       echo "start time :".strftime('%c')."<br>";
        $Thread = new SiteProcess($Storage, $site,$query);      
        $Thread->start();  
        $Threads[$re] = $Thread;

    }

    foreach($Threads as $Thread)
    {
        $Thread->join();

    }


    ?>
```

Output :

```
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:50 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:52 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:54 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:55 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:58 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:29:59 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:30:02 2014
start time : Thu Mar 12 10:30:03 2014
```

**PHP threads not executing in  Multithreading  manner**.I think code execute one by one not in parallel.I am try to use Stackable Class but not working.

**Is what i am seeing correct? Or am i doing something wrong here?**

My Core PHP code looks like :

```
  $query="test";
  $sits=array('demo1','demo3','demo2','demo3','demo4','demo5','demo6','demo7','demo8');

  foreach($sites as $site)
    { 

    require_once 'Sites/'.$site.'.php';
    $siteObj = new $site;
    $data = $siteObj->getPriceData($query);

    }
```

Comment: ```$Threads[$re]```, count of $Threads is max 1, that's why they run one at a time ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins thnx for replay..can you tell me working code

Comment: @JoeWatkins how can give max count to $Threads

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220074/php-pthread-doesnt-seems-to-be-multithreading  Perhaps that can help